# Как связать html + NodeJS

Tags: node.js

Я новичок в NodeJS, по этому наверное у меня такой дурацкий вопрос. Поясните пожалуйста **как отобразить текст из переменной NodeJS в HTML файле**. То есть, если в php я могу сделать так:

`<p> <?php $someText ?> </p>`

Как добиться того же результата, с помощью Node?

Comment: напиши используемый стек технологий и покажи код, которым ты обрабатываешь запросы

Comment: https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html

Comment: Ну вообще у Node.js все лежит на сервере ... в отличии от php он не может вот так динамично фигачить он при запуске собирает все страницы из jade или другого шаблонизатора и отдает... ну или на худой конец просто отдает статичную html заготовленную вами заранее

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NodeJS - это программная среда для запуска JS-кода вне браузера.
Таким образом для того, чтобы отобразить значение переменной из вашего
приложения, запущенного под NodeJS, оно как минимум должно быть сервером,
который вернёт значение этой переменной в ответ на запрос с вашей HTML-страницы.

Скорее всего вы имели ввиду как добавить значение в HTML из JS-скрипта 
прямо у вас на странице. В таком случае укажите в тегах `<script>...</script>`
после закрывающего тега `</body>` следующее:

```
document.getElementById("id элемента, 
в который вы хотите вставить значение").innerHTML = "значение";
```

В данном случае вы сначала определяете с каким элементов вы будете работать,
а затем, с помощью его свойства `innerHTML` указываете нужное внутреннее значение. Однако такой способ подстановки значений в HTML-разметку не всегда удобен.

Если же вы имели ввиду непосредственную вставку ответа севера на страницу,
то используйте этот же способ в функции обработчика ответа, однако
запрос на сервер в таком случае должен быть произведён средствами 
`fetch` или `ajax` чтобы не привести к перезагрузке страницы